# What is wrong with my definition of Zip in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, zip, combinators

```
--  eg. myzip [’a’, ’b’, ’c’] [1, 2, 3, 4] -> [(’a’, 1), (’b’, 2), (’c’, 3)]
myzip :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [(a,a)]
myzip list1 list2 = [(x,y) |  [x, _] <-list1, [y,_] <-list2 ]
```

I get this error message:

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a = [a]
    When generalising the type(s) for `myzip'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three problems: One is the pattern match, one is the type signature, and one is the nature of the list comprehension.  Here is a corrected version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
myzip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a, b)]
myzip xs ys = [(x, y) | x <- xs | y <- ys]
```

- The original type signature, `[a] -> [a] -> [(a, a)]`, meant that both lists had to have the same type of element.  The `Ord a` was superfluous, and just meant that certain types of elements were disallowed.
- The pattern `[x, _] <- list1` means that each element of `list1` must be a two-element list.  Use `x <- list1` instead.
- The two list comprehensions are in series instead of parallel.  Think of the comma as, "Take items from list1, then from list2" (series).  Think of the two pipes as being parallel.

The difference between series and parallel:

```
> [[x, y] | x <- "abc", y <- "123"] -- series
["a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"]
> [[x, y] | x <- "abc" | y <- "123"] -- parallel
["a1","b2","c3"]
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that parallel list comprehensions aren't standard haskell (which is why they have to be enabled as a ghc extension).

Answer (score 6):

If you re-writing `zip` in order to gain insight into Haskell, I'd suggest that you try to write it without using list comprehensions. List comprehensions are powerful, but are somewhat like a convenient shorthand for some particular cases in Haskell. And, as you see, to use them in other cases might require non-standard extensions (such as `ParallelListComp`).

Think about what `zip` needs to do in the general case, and what happens if the general case isn't met (which can happen in two ways!). The equations for the function should fall naturally out of that.